# Backbone not rest the property values when initialize

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I just found out Backbone not reset the property values when creating a new instance (only for objects and arrays). I have created a simple JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/samitha/fb5chvbv/) demonstrate this behavior. After having a closer look this happens because the way backbone handle the prototype chain.

```
tmpI: 0,
tmpO: {
    t: 0
},
tmpA: [0],
```

values in following object not get reset when creating a new instance. First run
I, O & A will = 0. When recreate a new instance then values are I = 0 but O & A = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript prototype values are shared between instances. 
Objects and arrays are mutable, meaning changing a nested value will mutate the original object that lives on the prototype and will not set an instance level one.

Long story short, the rule of thumb is to set methods on the prototype and data on the instance level.

If you want unique values, set them on the instance level and not on the prototype.

What you need is something like this:

```js
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#root'),
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('init::BaseView');
        this.tmpI = 0
        this.tmpO = {t: 0}
        this.tmpA = [0],
    },
    baseViewMethod: function () {
        console.log('a base view method');
    },
    spinnerToggleFunctions: {}, //function () { return {} },

    preRender: function () {
        console.log('*** I: %o O: %o A: %o', this.tmpI, this.tmpO.t, this.tmpA[0]);
        this.tmpI = 1;
        this.tmpO.t = 1;
        this.tmpA[0] = 1;
        //this.spinnerToggleFunctions[new Date()]=1;
        //console.log('*** %o', this.spinnerToggleFunctions);
        //this.spinnerToggleFunctions={};
    },

    postRender: function () {
        console.log('*** I: %o O: %o A: %o', this.tmpI, this.tmpO.t, this.tmpA[0]);
        this.tmpI = 2;
        this.tmpO.t = 2;
        this.tmpA[0] = 2;
    },

    render: function () {
        this.preRender();
        this.$el.html("Time"+ new Date().toJSON());
        this.postRender();
    },
    destroy: function () {
        this.remove();
        this.unbind();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not Backbone.js's issue.

```
spinnerToggleFunctions: {}, //function () { return {} },
tmpI: 0,
tmpO: {
    t: 0
},
tmpA: [0]
```

You'd probably know this but `tmpI,tmpO and tmpA` in the code above from your sample are BaseView's properties which will be accessed via proto from its instances.

and when you

```
    this.tmpI = 1;
    this.tmpO.t = 1;
    this.tmpA[0] = 1;
```

you are making instances new property at `this.tmpI` so now the instance has its own property named `tmpI` which means it doesnt have to check if `__proto__` has a property called `tmpI`

but where you call `this.tmpO.t = 1;` and `this.tmpA[0] = 1` are not creating the instance's property but changing `__proto__`'s property directly.

it's all because You can not create Array or Object member before the Array or Object is defined.to avoid this,

```
    this.tmpI = "";
    this.tmpO = {};
    this.tmpA = [];
    this.tmpI = 1;
    this.tmpO.t = 1;
    this.tmpA[0] = 1;
```

now you are creating and changing the instance properties.prototype property never get changed.

```
 init::BaseView
(index):46 *** I: 0 O: 0 A: 0
(index):59 *** I: 1 O: 1 A: 1
(index):33 init::BaseView
(index):46 *** I: 0 O: 0 A: 0
(index):59 *** I: 1 O: 1 A: 1
```

ofc once you delete instance properties, @tmpI,tmpO,tmpA are pointing to prototype properties again.

```
preRender: function () {
    console.log('*** I: %o O: %o A: %o', this.tmpI, this.tmpO.t, this.tmpA[0]);
    this.tmpI = "";
    this.tmpO = {};
    this.tmpA = [];
    this.tmpI = 1;
    this.tmpO.t = 1;
    this.tmpA[0] = 1;
    delete this.tmpO;
    delete this.tmpA;
    delete this.tmpI;
    console.log('deleted instance propeties so these are prototype properties.  I: %o O: %o A: %o', this.tmpI, this.tmpO.t, this.tmpA[0]);
},
```